# Custom control in Windows Phone 8.1 & Windows 8.1 with subitems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

For one of my projects I need to create a custom control that contains sub-items and I need to be able to add these sub-items in XAML code. I mean something like this:

```
<controls:CustomControl>
    <controls:CustomControl.Item>

    </controls:CustomControl.Item>
</controls:CustomControl>
```

I did a search in Google and found some sample codes but all of them were for WPF and not Windows Phone. I found the usage of [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)], but it's not available in Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1.

What's the best way for creating custom controls that may contain sub-items inside and can be edited in XAML code?

Comment: brief a little more what you want to achieve.. b'coz the purpose of making custom control should be to write CustomControl.Items inside the custom control itself, not in the page where you use CustomControl.

Comment: Consider I'm going to create a custom Tab Control that in which several Tab Pages can be added. Of course the Tab Pages must be defined inside the Tab Control which is a custom control. I want to create a custom control that its tab pages can be added using the XAML code as well. Not only in code. Does that make sense?

Comment: Then i think you should use "ItemPresenter" control in the CustomControl that you make. That itemPresenter will be the Items inside that custom control which can be written in XAML page.

Answer (score 0):

To implement custom TabControl you should create a custom control derived by the Panel class and overide MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods to implement custom layout.

[XAML custom panels overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn592167.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my concern is how can I create a reusable custom control so users can add items to it in XAML? Like the sample XAML code in my question but for unlimited items. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you so mush. It worked for me finally. :) Now my another question is how can I make a sub-item visible only inside the parent control XAML tag? I mean I don't want a custom TabItem to be definable separately in the XAML code.

Comment: @Alireza I don't know how to do it. My opinion is you don't have to implement it.